# c++ order of defs in the class, surprise

Tags: c++

Stroustrup states in C++ Language book that order of definitions in the class does not matter.
Indeed:

```
class C1 { 
       int foo() { return bar(); }    // where is bar() ?
       int bar() { return m_count; }  // oh, here is bar(). but where is m_count ?
       int m_count;                   // here is m_count. Better late than never !
}
```

This compiles. Despite misordering. As promised. 
So far, so good.

However, this does not compile:

```
class C2 {
      void baz(Inner *p) {} // we were promised that order does not matter
                            // is Inner defined ?
      struct Inner {};      // yes, Inner is define here.
};
```

This looks a contradiction to Stroustrup's promise of free ordering inside the class. Quoting Stroustrup: "A member function declared within a class can refer to every member of the class as if the class were completely defined before the member function bodies were considered".

Does anybody know a ref to standard clause that allows C1 and disallows C2 ? I am curious why C2 was disallowed while C1 is allowed. Is it compiler bug that contradicts the standard, maybe ?

Comment: I think you need to quote Stroustrup word for word if you want us to resolve this. What did he write exactly?

Comment: TonyK. Stroustrup writes "A member function declared within a class can refer to every member of the class as if the class were completely defined before the member function bodies were considered".

Comment: In that case, it seems that Stroustup's statement is false (although it may have been true when he wrote it). The new C++0x draft standard says: "Members of a class are data members, member functions, nested types, and enumerators."

Comment: That's why I asked ... I am fairly sure all the talk about declarations vs definitions belong to some other question.

Comment: My feeling was that intention of language designers was to make it as in Stroustrup promise. Compiler writers botched it, probably for reason mentioned byn.m. Or they did not standard attentively enough :-; I tested in C++03. Maybe it's fixed in C++0x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An identifier that denotes a **type** must be declared prior to use. This has to do with the complicated structure of C++ grammar. The compiler simply cannot parse certain code if it does not know beforehand which identifiers are types.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the following compiles fine (in VS2008):

```
class C2 {
  void baz() {  Inner* i = new Inner(); }
  struct Inner {}; 
};
```

There are two differences between your two examples.  The first uses an undeclared **symbol** inside the **body** of a function and the second uses an undeclared **type** in the **signature** of the function.

I suspect that my example and your first example both work because the function bodies aren't resolved until after the entire class declaration has been parsed.  The function signatures have to make sense as soon as they are encountered.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing "declarations" with "definitions". The inner class *must* be declared - if only forward declared - before it can be used.

Comment: And a forward declaration only helps if it is used as a pointer or reference, otherwise the compiler needs the complete type definition

Comment: This is not an answer al all. Both m_count and Inner lack preliminary declaration. Yet one allows usage before declaration, and another does not. Technically, "int m_count;" and "struct Inner {}" are both definitions. Can you explain why one can come after use, and another cannot? Both having no previous declaration ?

Comment: Some declarations are also definitions, which *does* confuse things. class A; and extern int m_count; are only declarations. A class has to be declared before it can be used in another class's definition.

Comment: Keep in mind that your inline functions are definitions of the functions. You can declare the functions first and define them later.

Comment: To rubenvb: Actually, in the case given, a forward declaration is all that is required.

Comment: John: my examples C1 and C2 above, contain *only* definitions. Where do you think there is declaration in C1 or C2, that I am "confusing" with definition ? Can you point at one ?

Comment: Even though you have the function inlined, it still has a declaration. When the compiler parses the declaration of the function baz, it is running across an unknown type (Inner). That causes the error. The problem isn't because Inner is not defined (i.e., the order of definition isn't causing the problem). The problem is that Inner isn't declared.

Answer (score 2):

The order of definition does not matter, but the order of declaration does.

In C++, a declaration means (roughly) stating the "kind" or type of a symbol:

- `class A;` --> A is of kind "class"
- `void foo(int);` --> foo is a function that takes an int and returns nothing

A definition, however, fully defines what the symbol relates to. As in C, a definition happens to be a declaration too.

Finally, to muddy the waters further, for user-declared types, sometimes a definition is required (complete-type) while sometimes a simple declaration is sufficient...

Now, let us revise your issue, I'll illustrate it with a simple example using C++0x:

```
struct A {
  void foo() { ++count; }
  void bar(decltype(count) c); // error: 'count' was not declared in this scope

  int count;
};

struct B {
  void foo() { Inner a; a.foo(); }
  void bar(Inner& i); // error: 'Inner' has not been declared

  struct Inner { void foo(); };
};
```

As you can notice, `A::foo` is parsed correctly, while `A::bar` is not.

The issue comes from the fact that the compiler "cheats": the methods body are fully analyzed only once the class has been completely parsed. Therefore it is fine to refer to a yet undeclared type/attribute/function in a function body, but it is not fine to refer to it in a function signature (declaration).

You could say that to the compiler, the code is equivalent to:

```
struct A {
  void foo();
  void bar(decltype(count) c); // error: 'count' was not declared in this scope

  int count;
};
void A::foo() { ++count; }

struct B {
  void foo();
  void bar(Inner& i); // error: 'Inner' has not been declared

  struct Inner { void foo(); };
};
void B::foo() { Inner a; a.foo(); }
```

Stroustrup sentence is "easy", but not necessarily accurate. For example, using `Inner` as an attribute requires that it is fully defined (only complete types may be used as non static attributes), which can cause further grief.

```
struct C {
  struct Inner;

  Inner foo; // error: field 'foo' has incomplete type

  struct Inner { };
};
```

Though one could argue that `Inner foo` is a declaration and thus not covered by Stroustrup's quote.

Comment: "takes an int and returns nothing" -- what a rude and greedy foo! Aside from that, this is exactly what I wanted to write if my iPhone hadn't died while typing the answer, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the promise of free ordering inside the class is held if you split declaration and definition (into a header and an implementation file). Once you split them, the order really doesn't matter anymore.