# How can my private method access public enum in C++?

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, enums

I would like to know how or if I can make my public `enum payloadTypes` accessible to my private method `threshold()` in my following class:

```
class A {

private: 
    unsigned int  threshold(payloadTypes kindOfPayload,int x,int y);

public:
 enum payloadTypes {
  INVALID =-1,
  TEST=0,
  THRESHOLDS,
  RX,
 };

}
```

I am getting this error if I do as above, and I don't want to change the scope of my enum to `private`

> error: 'payloadTypes ' has not been declared
>
> unsigned int  threshold(payloadTypes kindOfPayload,int x,int
>   y);

Comment: Can you clarify whether `thresholdGetter` is a function different from `threshold`, or whether it's just a "typo" in your question?

Comment: @Angew you're right it was a "typo"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler error is about `thresholdsGetter()`, but your code presented is about `threshold()`. In case the compiler error is the truth, then you need to change your prototype from:

```
unsigned int  thresholdsGetter(payloadTypes kindOfPayload,int x,int y);
```

to this:

```
unsigned int  thresholdsGetter(A::payloadTypes kindOfPayload,int x,int y);
```

That way `A::payloadTypes` resolves the enum, given that it's defined before the function. As a mention below, enums cannot be forwarded.

---

In case the code you posted is the truth, the following hold true:

The problem is that when you declare your function, the enum is not declared or defined.

This will work:

```
class A {

public:
 enum payloadTypes {
  INVALID =-1,
  TEST=0,
  THRESHOLDS,
  RX,
 };

private:
unsigned int  threshold(payloadTypes kindOfPayload,int x,int y);

};
```

However, you cannot forward declare the enum. Read more in [Forward declaring an enum in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c).

Comment: This is not correct. Note that `thresholdsGetter` is *not* part of the class definition.

Comment: @Bathsheba what do you mean? The function is a member function of `class A`, isn't it?

Comment: No, `threshold` is, not `threseholdsGetter`.

Comment: @Bathsheba sorry for double questioning you, updated! BTW, nice answer of yours there.

Comment: No worries. That's what SO comments are for. This is a nice answer now. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 6):

Since `thresholdsGetter` is not part of the class definition, you need to write `A::payloadTypes` rather than `payloadTypes` since Argument Dependent Lookup cannot come to the rescue.

Alternatively, do you have a typo in your implementation of `threshold`? You've written `thresholdsGetter`, according to the compiler error. But despite what Stroustrup says<sup>1</sup>, you still need to declare your `enum` *before* the function in your class definition. If you correct that then your code will work as it is.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that

```
struct foo
{
    enum bar {};
    void foobar(bar b){}
};
```

*will* compile, but

```
struct foo
{
    void foobar(bar b){}
    enum bar {};
};
```

will *not*.

Comment: Probably a typo yeah, it's amazing when OP doesn't paste the code but just rewrites it.

Comment: Are you sure? When I compile the class (with the enum declared later in the class), I get the error: `unknown type name 'payloadTypes'`. Moving the enum before the function removes the error.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281083/c-order-of-defs-in-the-class-surprise), for example.

Answer (score 4):

You must declare the enum before using it.

```
class A {
public:
    enum payloadTypes {
        INVALID = -1,
        TEST = 0,
        THRESHOLDS,
        RX,
    };
private:
    unsigned int  threshold(payloadTypes kindOfPayload, int x, int y);

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment, that solution is exactly the one provided by @gsamaras.

Comment: Oops. I am wrong here. Trivial edit to convert a downvote to an upvote. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

**Nothing in C++ can be used without declaring it before usage** or *forward declaring* it. Its not an issue with public or private at all. Its simply an issue that when you are using the enum in the function it is not yet declared. However an enum cannot be forward declared, so you will have to swap the public & private blocks to make it work.